# Optimizing Kafka Performance in Docker: Single ZooKeeper vs. Multiple, Broker Count Impact

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm running a Kafka cluster within Docker and exploring different configurations for optimal performance. I have four scenarios in mind:

Scenario 1: Two Kafka servers with two brokers each (ksrv1:9092,9093 & ksrv2:9092,9093), served by a single ZooKeeper.

Scenario 2: Same as Scenario 1, but with two or three ZooKeepers for increased fault tolerance.

Scenario 3: Each Kafka server with a single broker and a dedicated ZooKeeper.

Scenario 4: Similar to Scenario 3, but multiple ZooKeepers for high fault tolerance.

which scenario has better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore. It especially should not be "one / multiple per broker". Kafka clusters can have tens of brokers, but only need up to 7 Zookeeper, max. If you use Kraft mode, then you need zero.

Multiple brokers (or Zookeeper) on a single host is unlikely to improve performance. Your single disk, cpu, and RAM will be the limiting factors, especially if data starts replicating within the same host disk

Comment: What if the container with ZooKeeper that watches the brokers fails? I want to know about fault tolerance and costs, forget about performance.

Comment: Like I said, Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper. And it'll be removed in future releases completely. So, forget about that. If the Kraft controller fails, then the cluster is down. You're welcome to multiple Kraft controllers. You explicitly asked to optimize performance